# Connect database protected with htaccess in PhpStorm

Tags: database, apache, .htaccess, phpstorm

I have a database hosted in a remote server that I'd like to connect to PhpStorm. This URL is protected by a login system handled through .htaccess/.htpasswd, and thus PhpStorm can't achieve to connect to the URL.

Is there a way to specify the credentials defined in my .htpasswd to PhpStorm, so it authenticates to it before trying to access the database?

Comment: What does .htaccess have to do with a database? Do you mean that you only have access to the database through a web-based administration console? If so, I don't think you're going to have much luck - PHPStorm is going to want to connect to the database itself, not the admin tool.

Comment: The .htaccess is restricting access to the PhpMyAdmin login page. I can access it through web browser but I need to enter the credentials.
I followed a guide from DigitalOcean much like [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-12-04) to configure it

Comment: Right, so as I thought: PhpMyAdmin is an administration tool, which in turn connects to the actual database running on the remote server. It allows *you* to view and manage the database, because it's a UI for humans. Unless there's some freaky API I'm not aware of, this won't be any good for PhpStorm, which needs to talk to the actual database itself, not just an admin tool.

Comment: PhpStorm works with database directly (MySQL in your case). Generally speaking -- Database functionality of PhpStorm can be treated as local equivalent of PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm using MySQL driver (since Phpmyadmin uses this DBMS).
So the only solution would be to export the remote database to have it localy-hosted, and make PHPStorm use the local copy of this DB ?

Comment: You MySQL database is most likely not directly accessible from internet (assuming that we are talking about MySQL on some remote server, e.g. shared hosting). if so -- your only option would be connecting via SSH tunnel.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help, I'll go for the SSH solution then!

Comment: @MaximeFlament Based on your comments ... you seems to have quite misunderstanding of how it all works. if you need local DB -- you will need local MySQL installation. Database functionality of PhpStorm as well as PhpMyAdmin are just admin tools / convenient interface to access your actual MySQL database -- they will not run/replace actual MySQL.

Comment: I understood the difference between both. Just that Phpstorm interface is misleading because it provides a connection through 'URL' and by URL, i thought it could be a distant administration tool such as Phpmyadmin, that Phpstorm would use to access MySQL and thus the database.